# prefetch_related() error in django while inner joining

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am create a code that is  inner join of two object ModelA and ModelB.
**model.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    custom_id = models.UUIDField(blank=False,null=False, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField("created", auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ModelB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Image", blank=True)
    important_note = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    auther = models.ManyToManyField(Auther, related_name="juries")
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField("created", auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Inner Join Code**

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            key = self.kwargs['pk']
            if key is not None:
                return ModelA.objects.filter(custom_id=key, is_deleted=False).prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('modelb_set', queryset=ModelB.objects.filter())) \
                    .order_by('-updated')
        except Exception:
            return ModelA.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('modelb_set', queryset=ModelB.objects.filter())) \
                .order_by('-updated')
```

And when I run it then I am getting below **error**

```
 raise AttributeError("Cannot find '%s' on %s object, '%s' is an invalid "
AttributeError: Cannot find 'modelb_set' on ModelA object, 'modelb_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

I checked some  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49170706/11360069) related to this but why I am getting below error in my code?

Where I did wrong? How can I fix?

Comment: Please add your models to the question...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have updated the code.

Comment: Your `ModelA` and `ModelB` are not even related in any way. Why do you expect `prefetch_related` to work here?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat How can we find that both model are not even related? I mean I want know how can detect this?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ok I can see in the given example link the circuit field are even related. That's the exact point. right?